# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined using React and useRef

Tags: reactjs

So this is the function that I handle outside the target click to close some models and stuff, but an error message on the console shows an error message like the following:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')`

And I'm wondering how to handle the `undefined` so the function doesn't call, or at least hide from the console.

Here is how I handle it:

```
 let useClickOutside = (handler) => {
        let domNode = useRef();

        useEffect(() => {
            let maybeHandler = (event) => !domNode.current.contains(event.target) && handler();
            document.addEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);
            return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);
        });

        return domNode;
    };
```

Comment: `if (!domNode.current) return` or just add `?` after `current`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, can you present a full example and also explain why I should do that, let's all learn, and those who can contribute to this big community to do so?, thanks.

Comment: I didn't answer because your question is most probably a duplicate. I see questions like this a few times a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `(?.)`

```
let useClickOutside = (handler) => {
        let domNode = useRef();

        useEffect(() => {
            let maybeHandler = (event) => !domNode.current?.contains(event.target) && handler();
            document.addEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);
            return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);
        });

        return domNode;
    };
```

**Solution 2**: Use [Logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) `(&&)`

```
 let useClickOutside = (handler) => {
        let domNode = useRef();

        useEffect(() => {
            let maybeHandler = (event) =>  domNode.current && !domNode.current.contains(event.target) && handler();
            document.addEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);
            return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", maybeHandler);
        });

        return domNode;
    };
```